# How to handle undefined error before useEffect execute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Have a little problem today. My online player is gathering songs from DB in useEffect and and saves in state like this:

```
 const [songs, setSongs] = useState([]);
 const [currentSong, setCurrentSong] = useState(songs[0]);

  async function getSongs() {
    const songsRes = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/song/");
    await setSongs(songsRes.data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getSongs();
  }, []);

  const songEndHandler = async () => {
    let currentIndex = songs.findIndex((song) => song.id === currentSong.id);
    await setCurrentSong(songs[(currentIndex + 1) % songs.length]);
    playAudio(isPlaying, audioRef);
    return;
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <audio
        onLoadedMetadata={timeUpdateHandler}
        onTimeUpdate={timeUpdateHandler}
        ref={audioRef}
        src={currentSong.audio}
        onEnded={songEndHandler}
      ></audio>
    </div>
  );
```

but in render i have  tag which requires currentSong.audio value, which is not yet loaded from the database and it throwing undefined error. How can I make the audio tag wait until the currentSong is set in state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

You initialize your `currentSong` state to an undefined value, `songs[0]` is undefined and so an error is thrown when accessing into it (`currentSong.audio`).

```
const [songs, setSongs] = useState([]);
const [currentSong, setCurrentSong] = useState(songs[0]);
```

## Solution

Set (or don't) better initial state:

```
const [songs, setSongs] = useState([]);
const [currentSong, setCurrentSong] = useState();
```

Conditionally render UI until `currentSong` is defined:

```
return (
  <div>
    {currentSong && (
      <audio
        onLoadedMetadata={timeUpdateHandler}
        onTimeUpdate={timeUpdateHandler}
        ref={audioRef}
        src={currentSong.audio}
        onEnded={songEndHandler}
      />
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding.

```
src={currentSong && currentSong.audio}
```

or

```
src={currentSong?.audio}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Optional chaining operator ?. Try this hope it solve your problem

```
 <audio
    onLoadedMetadata={timeUpdateHandler}
    onTimeUpdate={timeUpdateHandler}
    ref={audioRef}
    src={currentSong?.audio}
    onEnded={songEndHandler}
  ></audio>
```